# jest can't find 'menu' property in json object

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

In my test I mock some data as I will receive it from backend so it has this structure

```
mockCompteContexte = {
        menu: {
            menu: {...},
            submenus: [...]
        },
        routes: {...}
}
```

And I use it as a value for a provider

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [...],
            providers: [
                { provide: CompteContextService, useValue: mockCompteContexte},
                ...
            ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

But however I try to reach it in the test, the menu property is undefined while the routes property is readable. If I rename the menu property it's not undefined anymore.

Is 'menu' a keyword which should not have been used in the data structure or is there a way to access it?

I'm using jest 24.9.0 and jest-preset-angular 7.1.1

Comment: That's a really bizarre error unfortunately. The only thing I can think of is that you are sharing the same object in all your tests rather than creating a new one, do any of your tests modify that object?

Comment: No, there's no test which will modify this object, it's used as a config file/data defined by the back end